# Continue Run Twitter Streaming API in Background

Tags: php, api, ubuntu, supervisord, nohup

I'm utilizing twitter streming api in PHP and it's working fine. I had used that [repo](https://github.com/spatie/twitter-streaming-api). I had following code  and suppose it's running by hitting mywebsite.com/stream

```
PublicStream::create(
$accessToken,
$accessTokenSecret,
$consumerKey,
$consumerSecret
)->whenFrom([
        [-180, -90, 180, 90] // Whole world
], function(array $tweet) {
    echo "{$tweet['user']['screen_name']} just tweeted {$tweet['text']} with a location attached";
})->startListening();
```

Now if I **run mywebsite.com/stream in browser** or do in terminal **curl mywebsite.com/stream** then it's working fine unless I close the browser or terminal also it sometimes give error of maximum execution time reached.

Now i wanted to run the process in background so that if I close the terminal then it continue to run unless I intentionally stop it.

I have figured out two options

1. Use nohup in Linux to run the process in background
2. Use process monitoring tool like supervisor to run the process

In either case what I have to run? like I need to run this thing in background? ALso this is the best approach in my case?

> curl mywebsite.com/stream